# Very confused on this part , two network interface Card(NIC) are configured on server

Tags: networking, route-server

i am very much confused on this scenario . This is first time  i am seeing two NIC cards are configured for server ,now my query is how to route traffic initiated at server end for NIC interfaces

Comment: That's actually nothing special. Do you connect the NICs to different networks or to the same network for redundancy/aggregation?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure persistence routes  in servers according to  the traffic requirement .

When two NIC are configured in server assume in

=>.  `In Nic 1 configure ip address , subnetmask ,and gateway . A default route is added in persistence route table in server`

As destination 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 gateway pointing to NIC1

=> `In NIC 2 Configure IP address , subnetmask , and leave gateway Configuration as empty`

Now add specific routes as per traffic requirement pointing towards NIC2.

Comment: Well said ! I have been fallowing your posts since 1 year . it's been great contribution for beginners like me .to understand more  into practical..